# How to create library that depends on ionic 2/angular 2 and uses Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, npm, angular, ionic2

to provide some **context** to our problem:

My team and I are developing an Ionic 2 app that has several customer-versions. Even though the app functionalities are about the same, the different customer-versions have different settings, names and slight changes in the views. So the core of the app is the same in all the customer-versions of the application.

To manage the core code in these different customer-versions of the app, we would like to be able to update them quickly and easily.

Our thought was to create an NPM package that contained the core functionalities, models, enums, etc. Using NPM we would be able to update the main project, publish that to NPM as a package, and install that package in our different customer-versions. This way, the core code would be easily manageable, and no copying of code would be required, as we would only need to run `npm update [package-name]` and commit that change in package.json to source-control.

So we've tried doing just that, creating the core of the application as an NPM package and having the applications refer to the NPM package instead of their included core code (which we are trying to replace with said NPM package). Testing this with several classes was a success, until we stumbled onto injectable services. When the injectable service depended on a Dependency Injection (DI), the code would break and would provide the following error log;

**Problem**:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for AuthHttp! (TabsPage -> AuthService -> ApiService -> AuthHttp)
```

*Keep in mind that the core code in our customer-versions of the app works fine when it is inside the app itself, it's only not functional when it's being used by the NPM package*

This error occurs on the TabsPage, which is the root page of our application. The app checks if the user is authenticated with Auth0 by using the AuthService, if not, it opens an Auth0 lock (which is the login page of Auth0), nothing special happening here.
If authentication is successful or the user is already authenticated, the user profile that corresponds to that Auth0 user is retrieved from our database using the ApiService, which in turn uses the AuthHttp library to fetch the user from our C# WebApi.

The error says there is no provider for AuthHttp, even though it is set in our @App decorator of App.ts of the customer-version app:

```
// imports above
@App({
    template: '<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
    providers: [ApiService, CartService, UtilService, AppSettings, AuthService,
        provide(AuthHttp, {
            useFactory: (http) => {
                return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
            },
            deps: [Http]
        })
    ],
    config: {
    } // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class AppNameApp {
    // Set starting root page of the app to TabsPage
    rootPage: Type = TabsPage;

    constructor(platform: Platform){
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(AppSettings.appStatusBarColorHexString);
        });
    }
}
```

I understand that there is no AuthHttp provider in the NPM package, which could be the root of this problem, I just don't know how to get that done.

Do you have any suggestions? I am also open to other solutions to easily update the core code of our customer-versions of the app.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in your providers:

```
@App({
  template: '<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, // <--------------
    ApiService, CartService, UtilService, AppSettings, AuthService,
    provide(AuthHttp, {
        useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
        },
        deps: [Http]
    })
  ],
  config: {
  } // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
```

It's required since you have `Http` as dependency of your `AuthHttp` provider.

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not solve my problem. I want to emphasise the fact that the app works perfectly when the core code is *inside* the project, and not being used from the NPM package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late. Have the problem with translate service. Manage to fix it through adding this code to typescript configuration.

```
"paths": {
 "@angular/*": [
   "../node_modules/@angular/*"
 ],

 "@ngx-translate/*" : [
   "../node_modules/@ngx-translate/*"
 ]
```